# How to pass Mono<> result from previous step to the next doOnSuccess() method

Tags: java, spring, spring-webflux, project-reactor

Let's say that I have a method `addVoteToSong` like:

```
public Mono<Map<Song, VoteKind>> addVoteToSong(Principal principal, String songId, VoteKind voteKind) {
        return
            userRepository.findUserByUsername(principal.getName())
            .doOnSuccess(song -> songRepository.findSongById(songId))
            .doOnSuccess(vote -> voteRepository.add(Vote.builder().song()))
            .//(the rest of the code) 
}
```

I want to pass a result from the line:

```
userRepository.findUserByUsername(principal.getName())
```

and

```
.doOnSuccess(song -> songRepository.findSongById(songId))
```

to the built object in the line:

```
.doOnSuccess(vote -> voteRepository.add(Vote.builder().song(here result from findSongById).user(here result from findUserByUsername))
```

Here comes the question, is it possible to reuse previous API call result in the next `doOnSuccess` method or I should split find API calls at the same time, giving up on Reactor's cascading operations? On the internet, I have found examples with single `save` method without basing on the indirect result of the reactive stream and that's why question occurred. I will be grateful for suggestions on how to reach a goal.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Martin,

First of all, be aware that `.doOnXXX` are [just callbacks](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/Mono.html#doOnSuccess-java.util.function.Consumer-) that will be executed on some archived conditions. You should avoid putting a business logic inside of them.

Coming back to the question, the first idea that comes to my mind is to benefit from `zip` operator. So you have to put 2 publishers `.findUserByUsername` and `.findSongById` and combine the result using `BiFunction`. So you can try the following:

```
public Mono<Map<Song, VoteKind>> addVoteToSong(Principal principal, String songId, VoteKind voteKind) {
    return Mono
            .zip(
                    userRepository.findUserByUsername(principal.getName()),
                    songRepository.findSongById(songId),
                    (user, song) -> voteRepository.add(Vote.builder().song(song).user(user).build())
            )
            .flatMap(Function.identity())
            // your code is here
}
```

Comment: Holy moly, I didn't even know that this operator can be used in this way. Thank you so much, I will check this out tomorrow. Nonetheless, thank you so much. By the way, can you suggest any tutorial with real-life examples for Reactor?

Comment: yeah, it's an intention of `zip` operator to merge publishers and combine the result :) Please, let me know whether this will work for you.

Comment: to be frank, I don't really know the sources of reactor's production ready solutions in public. It's not so popular today but community is growing. Personally, I watched materials from Oleg Dokuka and also he published a book about Spring 5 and reactive programming. You can have a look

Comment: thanks for your answer. It's almost perfect, now when I am calling method zip I am receiving Mono<Mono<Vote>>. Is it possible to flat it to the single Mono<Vote>?

Comment: it's due to the fact that my add method returns Mono<Vote>.

Comment: @Martin I've updated my answer accordingly, please check whether it's working solution :)

Comment: if vote method creates a Mono, an alternative that might be more readable to some is to use a simplified version of `zip` that creates a `Mono<Tuple2>` and `flatMap` that into the `voteRepository.add` method: `Mono.zip(userRepo.find(xxx), songRepo.find(xxx)).flatMap(tuple -> voteRepository.add(Vote.builder().song(tuple.getT2()).user(tuple.getT1()).build()))`

Comment: @StepanTsybulski hello Stepan and sorry for the late answer. I was talking about a solution which will flat Mono<Mono<Vote>> to Mono<Vote>. I finally found and operator `zipWith` and current solution. Now with below code, it works as it supposes.

Comment: @StepanTsybulski code below because the comment is too long: 
`
`    return userRepository
        .findUserByUsername(ReactiveSecurityContextHolder.getContext()
            .map(SecurityContext::getAuthentication)
            .map(Authentication::getName)
            .toString())
        .zipWith(songRepository.findSongById(songId))
        .flatMap(pair -> voteRepository.add(Vote
            .builder()
            .song(pair.getT2())
            .user(pair.getT1())
            .voteKind(voteKind)
            .build()));
`
`

Comment: @Martin, thank you for sharing a working solution that fits to your needs. I'm glad that the answer was helpful for you :)